# Can I exclude itunes from the Software Update feature in system preference?

Tags: itunes, software-update, system-settings

I've reverted from 11 back to 10.7 three times by now because I keep forgetting to uncheck iTunes whenever it prompts me to install patches. I'd like to be able to tell the updater to skip over iTunes automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Software Update app, select the update and select `Ignore Update...` from the `Update` menu.

If you ever want to bring it back, select `Reset Ignored Updates` from the `Software Update` menu.